# MockServer in org.specs2 tests

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, specs2, mockserver

I use playframework 2.2.6 scala.

I want to write integration tests for my application. But my application requests some service by http and I want to mock it with [mockServer](http://www.mock-server.com/). But I don't know when to start and stop mockServer cause tests use futures

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class AppTest extends Specification with Around {

    def around[T](t: => T)(implicit e: AsResult[T]): Result = {

        val port = 9001

        val server = new MockServer()

        server.start(port, null)

        val mockServerClient = new MockServerClient("127.0.0.1", port)

        // mockServerClient rules

        val result = AsResult.effectively(t)

        server.stop()

        result
    }

    "Some test" should {

        "some case" in new WithApplication {

            val request: Future[SimpleResult] = route(...).get

            status(request) must equalTo(OK)

            contentAsString(request) must contain(...)
        }

        "some other case" in new WithApplication {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I have java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9001. And I can't do this without server.stop cause that server must be run in different tests.

Comment: Can you try with the `AroundEach` trait instead? This is the trait to use when you want to execute behaviour around each example. Then if you want to check futures, you can generally use `contain(...).await` provided that you have an implicit `ExecutionEnv` in scope: `class AppTest(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification with AroundEach`. I'll turn this into an answer if it works ok for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, I looked source code of WithApplication (it extends Around) and wrote abstract class WithMockServer:

```
abstract class WithMockServer extends WithApplication {

  override def around[T: AsResult](t: => T): Result = {

    Helpers.running(app) {

      val port = Play.application.configuration.getInt("service.port").getOrElse(9001)
      val server = new MockServer(port)

      val mockServerClient = new MockServerClient("127.0.0.1", port)

      // mockServer rules

      val result = AsResult.effectively(t)
      server.stop()
      result
    }
  }
}
```

And in each test cases I replaced `in new WithApplication` with `in new WithMockServer`